# What does 'relative' mean when we talk about refractive index?

Tags: refraction

What does it mean to say, "the refractive index of medium $B$ ***relative*** to medium $A$"? Assume that in this case, medium $A$ is optically denser than medium $B$.

I have difficulties trying to understand the word 'relative' in aforementioned quote. Does it mean refractive index of $A$ divided by the refractive index of $B$ or the other way round?

Comment: Can you please edit your question? It is unclear.

Comment: I want to know whether answer for this is mediumB\mediumA (or) mediumA\mediumB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental thing about a refractive index is that it measures the speed of electromagnetic propagation in the medium in question. It is the *ratio* of the speed of light in the vacuum to that in the medium. Its a *scale factor* that measures the speed of the light in the medium to that in a vacuum.

A "relative" refractive index simply means we broaden this idea so that the speed ratio is calculated with the "reference" medium different from a vacuum. Suppose we have two mediums $A,\,B$, with vacuum relative refractive indices $n_a,\,n_b$. Then the index of $A$ relative to $B$ is:

$$\frac{\frac{c}{n_b}}{\frac{c}{n_a}} = \frac{n_a}{n_b}$$

Notice how we divide the lightspeed in medium $B$ by that in $A$; the definition resorts to the wonted, vacuum relative refractive index when we put $n_b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

When somebody states that the refractive index of glass is $\frac 3 2$ then that is taken to mean the refractive index when light is going from a vacuum in glass and it is the ratio

$_{\rm vacuum}n_{\rm glass} = \dfrac{\text{speed of light in a vacuum}}{\text{speed of light in glass}}\approx \dfrac{3 \times 10^8}{2 \times 10^8}= \dfrac 3 2$

and this is often called the absolute refractive index and just written as $n_{\rm glass}$.

A vacuum is taken as the reference with a refractive index of one.

So the term refractive index of glass can be taken to mean refractive index of glass (medium $B$) relative to a vacuum (medium $A$).

This being the case then you can say that the optical density of medium $B$ is greater than medium $A$ noting that this is not the statement that you made in your question.

If the light is going in the opposite direction, ie from glass into a vacuum (optically more dense into optically less dense), then if you so choose you could define a relative refractive index for a vacuum relative to glass and its value will be

$_{\rm glass}n_{\rm vacuum} = \dfrac{\text{speed of light in glass}}{\text{speed of light in a vacuum}}\approx \dfrac{2 \times 10^8}{3 \times 10^8}= \dfrac 2 3$.

If you designate that the refractive index of going from medium $A$ to medium $B$ is $_{\rm A} n _{\rm B}$ and the absolute refractive index of medium $A$ is $_{\rm V}n_{\rm A}=n_{\rm A}$ and that of medium $B$ is $_{\rm V}n_{\rm B}= n_{\rm B}$ then it is relatively easy to show that

$_{\rm A}n_{\rm B} = \dfrac {n_{\rm B}}{n_{\rm A}}$

---

When dealing and interface between two mediums $A$ and $B$ where the angle in medium $A$ is $\theta_{\rm A}$ and the angle in medium $B$ is $\theta_{\rm B}$ it is perhaps easier to use absolute refractive indices (relative to a vacuum) as follows

$n_{\rm A} \sin \theta_{\rm A}=n_{\rm B} \sin \theta_{\rm B}$